# Подтянуть переменные package.json в tsconfig.json

Tags: node.js, typescript

Имеется package.json:

```
{
    "name": "some-project-name",
    "version": 1.0.0,
}
```

А также tsconfig.json

```
{
    "declarationDir": "dist/server-declaration",
    "outDir": "dist/server",
}
```

Могу ли я ключи из package.json встраивать в tsconfig.json, а именно в declarationDir и outDir чтобы в папке dist на выходе получалось так:

```
-dist/
  -some-project-name-1.0.0-declaration/
    -...
  -some-project-name-1.0.0/
    -...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. создай *(их содержимое ниже по тексту)*

   - package.json
   - script.js
2. запусти `npm start` , проверь вывод "package.name: some-project-name"
3. далее выбери сборщик

   - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/integrating-with-build-tools.html
4. реализуй в соответствии со своими хотелками

---

#### package.json

```json
{
    "name": "some-project-name",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node script.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "typescript": "^4.1.3"
    }
}
```

#### script.js

- https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scripts#packagejson-vars

> process.env.npm_package_name

```js
const package = new Proxy({}, { get(t, p, r) { return process.env[`npm_package_${p}`] } })
test: {
    console.log(`package.name: ${package.name}`)
}
```

Comment: P.S.: я глубоко верю в то, что [родной TSCompiler](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) можно использовать не только в консоли но и в JS скрипте, таким образом - вместо третьего пункта можно задаться изучением этого вопроса.